# Updating a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: A, B.

Here's what I want to do (this is obviously not valid SQL):

```
UPDATE A a, B b SET a.pic = b.pic WHERE a.my_id = b.my_id
```

i.e. when the column my_id matches in tables A and B, I want to copy the pic column from B to A.

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think this is a cross table update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct postgres query:

```
UPDATE A a
SET pic = b.pic
FROM B b
WHERE a.my_id = b.my_id;
```

Comment: yep.  docs may also be helpful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 0):

You're only really updating A (and you can only update one table in an an UPDATE statement anyways)

```
UPDATE A a SET a.pic = ( SELECT b.pic FROM B b WHERE a.my_id = b.my_id)
```

Comment: This query will set `a.pic` to `null` for the `a.my_id` that are not present in `B b`. Also after `SET` you must specify a column without table prefix. `SET pic` instead of `SET a.pic`